# Once the server is down, this snippet is keep calling the server repeately, how to stop?

Tags: java

Once the server is down, this snippet is keep calling the server repeatedly, how could I make it stop the repeated calling once the request fails? Maybe a catch/error block? But I'm not sure how to implement it. Thanks!

```
HttpURLConnection httpConn = null;
InputStream is = null;
OutputStream os = null;
String xmlResponse = null;

try {
   //Open Connection

       String CollectionId="123";
       String GetHTML="1";

       String urlString = "http://tester.com/webservices/ContentWS.asmx/GetCollection?CollectionId="+CollectionId+"&GetHTML="+GetHTML;

       System.out.println(urlString);

       //String encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(urlString,"UTF-8");

   URL url = new URL(urlString);
   httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

   //Setup Request
   httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
   httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
   httpConn.setReadTimeout(10000);
   httpConn.connect();

   xmlResponse = convertStreamToString(httpConn.getInputStream());
  }
  catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }

String htmlContent = "";
   try {
       DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
       DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
       InputSource input = new InputSource();
       input.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlResponse));

       Document doc = db.parse(input);
       NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Item");

       // iterate the Items
               int i = 0;
               int j = 0;
               Date now = new Date();
       for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                  //Grab HTML to append to htmlContent
                  NodeList teaser = doc.getElementsByTagName("Html");
                  Element line = (Element) teaser.item(i);
                  htmlContent += getCharacterDataFromElement(line);
       }
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
htmlContent = ...
```

Comment: Something of the code is missing. This code does not run endless

Comment: This question has nothing to do with JSP. Tag removed

Answer (score 0):

This code prints the stack trace, but doesn't throw the error, so your calling code doesn't know about the problem.

Does it help to make your catch() blocks rethrow the error?

```
e.printStackTrace();
throw e;
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to work. Your connection is opened and working, but you've forgotten a small detail. You must use `HttpURLConnection.disconnect()` when you are finished, to tell the program that you are done requesting information from the connection.

I look at networking in terms of Java like this:
Set up connection --> Send request for a connection --> connected --> Get data --> Do something with data --> Close the connection

And a quick note as far as `HttpURLConnection.disconnect()` goes, make sure that it will disconnect even if an exception is thrown. You could try adding the `} finally {` statement at the end if you'd like.